# forEach only execute the last element of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach, documentfragment

This is my code:

```
var Tree = ( function ( _Obj ) {
  var _E,
      _N;
  _Obj.forEach ( function ( e ) {
    _E = document.createDocumentFragment();
    if ( "tagName" in e ) {
      _N = document.createElement( e.tagName ); 
    }
    if ( "childNode" in e ) {
      _N.appendChild( Tree ( e.childNode ) );
    }
  });
  _E.appendChild ( _N );
  return _E;
});
```

And here the parameter of that function:

```
Fragment = [{ // firstNode
    "tagName" : "div",
    "childNode" : [{
      "tagName" : "p",
      "childNode" : [{
        "tagName" : "string",
        "childNode" : [{
          "tagName" : "span",
        }]
      }]
    }]
  },
  { //secondNode
    "tagName" : "div",
    "childNode" : [{
      "tagName" : "p",
      "childNode" : [{
        "tagName" : "span",
        "childNode" : [{
          "tagName" : "div"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
];
```

This code should return a document fragment with EVERY object of the `var Fragment`. If you look, the JSON is based on a `tagName` and `childNode` elements; for each object depends on one `tagName`, so the function return one new element with the same name.

But something goes wrong here, the function only returns the SECOND NODE of the `Fragment`:

```
#document-fragment
|_<div>
  |_<p>
    |_<span>
        <div></div>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

That this is equal to:

```
{
    "tagName" : "div",
    "childNode" : [{
      "tagName" : "p",
      "childNode" : [{
        "tagName" : "span",
        "childNode" : [{
          "tagName" : "div"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
```

But, what happend with the FIRST NODE?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your forEach loop goes through and assigns `_N` to the right stuff, but then only appends `_N` to `_E` after the entire loop has gone through. Move your `_E.appendChild(_N)` to the inside and bottom of your for each.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Tree = ( function ( _Obj ) {
  var _E,
      _N;
  _E = document.createDocumentFragment(); // put this out of forEach
  _Obj.forEach ( function ( e ) {
    if ( "tagName" in e ) {
      _N = document.createElement( e.tagName ); 
    }
    if ( "childNode" in e ) {
      _N.appendChild( Tree ( e.childNode ) );
    }
    _E.appendChild ( _N ); // put this inside of forEach
  });
  return _E;
});
```